# What's the exact basis of Z?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $G = span(g_1, g_2, g_3)$

$g_1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]^T$ 
$g_2 = [2, 2, 2, 3]^T$ 
$g_3 = [1, 1, 2, -1]^T$

And $Z$ is a subspace of $G$. 
Let's suppose $Z$ only has $[0, 0, \alpha, \beta]^T$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Then, $c_1g_1 + c_2g_2 + c_3g_3 = [0, 0, \alpha, \beta]^T$, $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ 
And, $c_1 = -5\alpha-2\beta, c_2=2\alpha+\beta, c_3=\alpha$

As we know, the conditions of basis are 1) generating set, 2) independent.

Like above, I think $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are a generating set of $Z$ and they are independent. 
So are $g_1,g_2,g_3$ basis of $Z$?

My friend is saying a basis of $Z$ is $[0,0,1,0]^T, [0,0,0,1]^T$ 
We know that there are many bases, but I don't think my friend's solution can't be found. 
Please help us to find the exact basis of $Z$.

Comment: And *what* is $Z$? Is it *the* subspace of $G$ which consist of *all* vectors of $G$ such that its first two coordinates are equal to $0$? Or is it *some* subspace of $G$  such that the first two coordinates of any of its vectors are equal to $0$?

Comment: @Aggyustic a basis for a subspace must be comprised of vectors in the subspace. If $$Z = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ \alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}: \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \cap G$$ then $g_1,g_2,g_3 \notin Z$, so they cannot be part of the basis. Since $Z$ is a subspace of $G$, your friend is only correct if $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\1\end{bmatrix} \in G$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for making my problem clear. Z is the subspace of G which consists of 'all' vectors of G such that its first two coordinates are equal to 0.

Comment: Try to use the previous comments to work out what a basis could be. Post progress.

Comment: Hint: you found that $c_1g_1+c_2g_2+c_3g_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ \alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix} \Longrightarrow c_1 = -5\alpha-2\beta, c_2 = 2\alpha+\beta, c_3 = \alpha$. So, try $\alpha = 1, \beta = 0$ or $\alpha = 0, \beta = 1$. Since both of these yield solutions, the two vectors your friend suggested are both within the span of $g_1,g_2,g_3$, and therefore, they are both vectors in $Z$. Since they span $Z$, they can be used as basis elements.